# Why is the main method calling compare() method twice?

Tags: java, if-statement

Here is the code,

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    compare(5);
}

public static void compare(int a) {
    if(a==5)
        System.out.println("The number is equal to 5");
    if(a<5)
        System.out.println("The number is less than 5");
    else
        System.out.println("The number is greater than 5");
}
}
```

Here is the output,

```
The number is equal to 5
The number is greater than 5
```

I have just called the compare method once, why is it executing twice?

Comment: Is it not being called twice, just once. But your `compare` method is printing two lines. Carefully look at it, and imagine what happens when you call it with the value 5...

Comment: Also, if you have any IDE (NetBeans, IDEA or Eclipse), you can use debugger to see what happens in your code.

Answer (score 10):

Because you have two `if-statements` with no relationship whatsoever. That's why it checks the parameter `a` twice with `a==5` and `a<5`.

You can fix it by extending the second if with an `else if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

It is not calling the method twice, but the consecutive if statements are the issue. Use

```
else if (a < 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add an else before your second **if** statement

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    compare(5);
}

public static void compare(int a) {
    if(a==5)
        System.out.println("The number is equal to 5");
    // added else
    else if(a<5)
        System.out.println("The number is less than 5");
    else
        System.out.println("The number is greater than 5");
}
}
```